# Implement those functions using matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, bioinformatics, biometrics

I have an array of samples of ECG signals 1250x1 double let us called it "a".
I need to implement 4 functions which represent features are used to characterize the signals. Energy, 4th Power,Nonlinear Energy and Curve Length

[image]

I manged to implement Energy and 4th Power

```
for i=1:1250
energy = sum(a.^2,i);

power4th =  sum(a.^4,i);
end
```

Which produce 2 array (energy and power4th)

How I can produce the other 2 array? let us called them NonLE and CL.

Comment: Have you tested your energy and 4th power. I don't think they will work unless your signal has 1250 dimensions.

Comment: Just to clarify you have a single array of size 1250x1 and the i in your equations goes along the 1250 dimension?

Comment: To simplify the `CurveLength` computation I would like to point out that it's a *telescoping series*, with result `a(end)-a(1)`. This is why I don't quite get why it should be called *CurveLength*, maybe a typo in the formula?

Comment: If your reference is this paper: http://www.s2is.org/Issues/v6/n5/papers/paper9.pdf I would like to point out that your formula for *CurveLength* is wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use vectorization instead of `for` loops to solve all 4 of the formulas you need

```
% generate some random numbers
a = rand(1000,1);

Energy = sum(a.^2);
Power4 = sum(a.^4);
NLEnergy = sum(-a(3:end).*a(1:end-2) + a(2:end).^2);
CurveLength = sum(a(2:end) - a(1:end-1));
```

The `.` operator allows element by element operations in a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think you can implement your formulas without using `for` loop. You can use matrix multiplication characteristic. Try the code below:

```
len      = 1250;
a        = randi(10, len, 1); % // You didn' t give your vector so I generated random a.. 
Energy   = ones(1, len) * (a.^2);
power4th = ones(1, len) * (a.^4);
NonLE    = ones(1, len - 2) * ( -a(3:end) .* a(1:end-2) ) +  ones(1, len - 1) * ( a(2:end).^2 );
CL       = ones(1, len - 1) * ( a(2:end) - a(1:end-1) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a `for` loop for 3 of them:

```
energy = sum(a.^2);
power_4th = sum(a.^4);
curve_length = sum(diff(a));
```

For the last one, you can do something like:

```
nonLE = 0;
for k = 3 : length(a)
    nonLE = nonLE + a(k - 1)^2 - a(k) * a(k - 2);
end
```